# How can I put numbers inside a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

In my code, the method is able to read the .txt file and puts the integers in one side of the array, and the double in another. However, in the output there are duplicates, and i'm trying to put them in ascending order with no duplicates.

```java
public static void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
  String[][] container = new String[2][2];
  int intIndex = 0;
  int doubleIndex = 0;
  while(s1.hasNextLine())
  {
    String line = s1.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
    for (String text : splitLine) {
        if (text.matches("\\d*")) 
        {
          System.out.println(text + " is int");
            if (container[0].length == intIndex) 
            {
                container[0] = Arrays.copyOf(container[0], intIndex + 2); //add two more slot to int array
                container[1] = Arrays.copyOf(container[1], intIndex + 2); //add two more slot to double array
            }
            container[0][intIndex] = (text); //add to container
            intIndex++; //adjust the index
        } else if (text.matches("\\d*.\\d*")) 
        {
            System.out.println(text + " is double");
            if (container[1].length == doubleIndex) 
            {
                container[0] = Arrays.copyOf(container[0], doubleIndex + 2); //add two more slot to int array
                container[1] = Arrays.copyOf(container[1], doubleIndex + 2); //add two more slot to double array
            }
            container[1][doubleIndex] = (text); //add to container
            doubleIndex++; //adjust the index
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println(text + " is not int nor double");
        }
    }
  }
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    Arrays.sort(container[0], Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())); //sort array of int
    Arrays.sort(container[1], Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())); //sort array of double
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(container[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(container[1]));
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
  }
```

The .txt file includes this all in one line, "10 5five 10 1.5 2 2.0 20"

I expect the output to be: 
[2, 10, 20]
[1.5, 2.0]

However, the actual output i get is:
[10, 10, 2, 20]
[1.5, 2.0, null, null]

Comment: Is there a reason you are incrementing the array size by 2? This will lead to potential nulls in the output. If you just want something like `[2, 10, 20]` you would have to increment the array size by 1 rather than two.

Comment: If either row gets filled,it should replace the array with one of size (2 x4) and copy all the numbers already read. If either row gets filled again, it should replace the array with one of size (2 x 8) and copy all the numbers already read.

Comment: What I mean is do you need both your double array and int array to have the same length? If you don't need them to be the same length then you can avoid null values entirely by increasing only the array you are adding to by 1.

Comment: Why yes, I'd like them to be the same length, though how could I deal with the duplicates in the output and in ascending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
    String[][] container = new String[2][2];
    int intIndex = 0;
    int doubleIndex = 0;
    while(s1.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = s1.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
        for (String text : splitLine) {
            if (text.matches("\\d*")) 
            {
                System.out.println(text + " is int");

                //checking the array for duplicates
                if (Arrays.stream(container[0]).anyMatch(text::equals)) {
                    continue;
                }


                if (container[0].length == intIndex) 
                {
                    container[0] = Arrays.copyOf(container[0], intIndex + 2); 
                    container[1] = Arrays.copyOf(container[1], doubleIndex + 2); 
                }
                container[0][intIndex] = (text); 
                intIndex++; //adjust the index
            } else if (text.matches("\\d*.\\d*")) 
            {
                System.out.println(text + " is double");

                //checking the array for duplicates
                if (Arrays.stream(container[1]).anyMatch(text::equals)) {
                    continue;
                }


                if (container[1].length == doubleIndex) 
                {
                    container[0] = Arrays.copyOf(container[0], intIndex + 2); 
                    container[1] = Arrays.copyOf(container[1], doubleIndex + 2); 
                }
                container[1][doubleIndex] = (text); 
                doubleIndex++; 
            } else 
            {
                System.out.println(text + " is not int nor double");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    //compare numerically rather than alphabetically in sorting
    Arrays.sort(container[0], Comparator.nullsLast((e1, e2) -> 
            Integer.valueOf(e1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(e2))));
    Arrays.sort(container[1], Comparator.nullsLast((e1, e2) -> 
            Double.valueOf(e1).compareTo(Double.valueOf(e2))));


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(container[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(container[1]));
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
}
```

Comment: It would be more effective to break down your changes or otherwise explain your fixes outside of the giant code block.

Comment: @Bakna I added some whitespace and comments around the lines I changed/added